# GitHub and build of a Windows .net 4.x web api project hosted on Azure

Tags: azure, yaml, continuous-integration, github-actions

Hi I'm new regarding the GitHub CI/CD pipeline, so sorry maybe for the trivial question but maybe others can have the same issue. For a customer I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue we have with the build process of a git workflow, I'm building an asp.net 4.8 web api application.

I have my run git workflow on GitHub but it fails with this error:

```
Run nuget restore
  nuget restore
  shell: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.EXE -command ". '{0}'"
  env:
    NUGET: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\nuget.exe\6.3.1\x64/nuget.exe
The folder 'D:\a\unified-reports\unified-reports' does not contain an msbuild solution or packages.config file to restore.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

From the error I understand that nuget.exe is running and working just fine but and I'm pretty sure (maybe I have to check or list that folder content in the job) that in the target folder D:\a\unified-reports\unified-reports there is a solution file (in the repo it exists and works fine).

So maybe the issue could be where nuget looks for a *.sln file? If yes how to specify it?

I already check other similar questions but all I found (in the GitHub context) is referred to the absence of nuget not exactly my issue.

Thanks for any help and/or suggestion!

I add below my yml omitting the deploy part.

```
name: Build and deploy ASP app to Azure Web App - XXXXXXXXX

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup MSBuild path
        uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.0.2

      - name: Setup NuGet
        uses: NuGet/setup-nuget@v1.0.5

      - name: Restore NuGet packages
        run: nuget restore

      - name: Publish to folder
        run: msbuild /nologo /verbosity:m /t:Build /t:pipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder /p:_PackageTempDir="\published\"

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: ASP-app
          path: '/published/**'
```

I've searched in the GitHub documentation and online for any similar error without any luck.

Comment: You can add a step to print out the files in that working folder (`ls` in PowerShell or `dir` in command prompt). That should tell what's exactly wrong.

Comment: Will try immediately